# Azure Cognitive Search: Field Mappings

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-search

I would like to set up a field mapping in cognitive search. I am using the web based UI, and the import data wizard to create an index and indexer.

I have tried, once having created the index and indexer using the wizard, to add a component to the JSON of the indexer, such as

```
"fieldMappings": [
    {
      "sourceFieldName": "metadata_storage_name",
      "targetFieldName": "new_storage_name"
    }
 ]
```

I then run the indexer, it is successful but when using the search Explorer, the field "new_storage_name" is null for all results.

I would really like to add a new field to obtain the unencoded "metadata_storage_path" and hit some problems, but since I am also stuck on this very basic step, I thought I would try to answer it first.

Is there something in the workflow I am getting wrong? I found the MS docs to not be too useful.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the base64Decode function.

```
"fieldMappings" : [
  {
    "sourceFieldName": "metadata_storage_name",
    "targetFieldName": "new_storage_name"
    "mappingFunction" : { 
      "name" : "base64Decode", 
      "parameters" : { "useHttpServerUtilityUrlTokenDecode" : false }
    }
  }]
```

Read more:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-indexer-field-mappings?WT.mc_id=Portal-Microsoft_Azure_Search&tabs=rest#mappingFunctions